# How to check input value length after paste?

Tags: html, jquery

I have an input field and the user can either type in a code or copy/paste it from an email.
I need to check the length of the input val() to activate a button afterwards, if the given value has a specific length. The length check works fine while typing, but not every time when pasting a value. The length is mostly 0 then - but not EVERY time. What am I doing wrong here, I don't get it? It should work EVERY TIME.

```js
$(document).on('keyup change paste click', '#promocode', function () {
    var code = $(this).val();

    $("#result").html(code.length);

    if (code.length == 8) {
        $("#result").html("length ok");
    }
    else {
        $("#result").html("NOT ok");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Copy/Paste a value into this field:
<form>
    <input type="text" id="promocode" placeholder="xxxx-xxx" />
    <div id="result">Enter value (8-digits)</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me (chrome/windows) your code worked with copy/paste and typing. The only time it failed was when I used right-click and paste. To fix that, I added the input event to your list. Now it works all the time.

```js
$(document).on('keyup change paste click input', '#promocode', function () {
    var code = $(this).val();

    $("#result").html(code.length);

    if (code.length == 8) {
        $("#result").html("length ok");
    }
    else {
        $("#result").html("NOT ok");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Copy/Paste a value into this field:
<form>
    <input type="text" id="promocode" placeholder="xxxx-xxx" />
    <div id="result">Enter value (8-digits)</div>
</form>
```

Comment: input... omg. How could I not know that? I was totally fixed on the paste event.. lol. Thank you so much, it works as it should now!

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $("#promocode").on('change keydown paste input propertychange click keyup blur', function(){
    if($('#promocode').val().length == 8){
    $("#result").html('okay');
    }
    else{
    $("#result").html('not okay');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="text" id="promocode" placeholder="xxxx-xxx" />
    <div id="result">Enter value (8-digits)</div>
```

try this, it includes methods which will fire when input changes. [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/7wkdjos6/)

Comment: Your solution works fine, thank you. I just selected @mankowitz answer as the accepted answer as he only added one (the missing) event to my existing solution.